# Publishing Golang Package and dependencies

Tags: go

How do you deal package dependencies? For example, say I have a package that I want to publish for all to use, and in developing that package I am using 3rd party packages. For this example lets say `github.com/gorilla/websocket` is one and `github.com/sirupsen/logrus` is another one. Will the go tools automatically see my “includes” and go get these packages? Do I have to put it my description that you need to have these installed before my package will work? Should I include them in my own sources somehow (which I doubt but not leaving anything out)? What is the recommended way to handle this? One thing to note is that I am using the Go 1.11 modules system so I do have my dependencies listed in my go.mod file. Is that enough?

Comment: Yes, `go get` will automatically fetch packages using import statements.  Yes, the module system will use go.mod files.

Comment: Thank you ThunderCat.  So knowing that, would you say it would probably be good practice to not use many dependencies unless really needed?  For example, I was about to get and install Logrus to do some debug logging which could be turned off when published but it would still be a dependency and so would still be fetched, even though in production it wouldnt be used. So probably not a good practice to use something like that would you say?

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. Given [the number of packages that import Logrus](https://godoc.org/github.com/sirupsen/logrus?importers), many package authors have no issue with the dependency.  I personally would try to make do with the standard log package rather than adding the dependency.

Comment: Yep.  I agree, and is what I have done here, just needed the validation for my thought process and you provided that.  Thank you sir for your help.  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry about this because `go get` will do it for you.